# Change img attr using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

Rather than use window width to change my img tags I want to use another elements height that is changed with media queries. So for example: the page is loaded on a full size (not mobile or tablet) monitor. When the window is shrunk and it reaches a break point of 800px the css sheets change and the height of a div tag named .content (in my code below) changes to 267px. Now I want jQuery to change the .attr of the image tag when .content <287 and then again on the next break point (<135).

I have tried my best to write the code but with no luck. I hope this makes sense and is an easy fix. I am very new to jQuery but I am learning for sure. Thank you in advance for any help. Here is the code in a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Margate/ze2GR/

```
        <html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Responsive Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var n = $(".content").height();
      if(n < 268){
      $("#pictureOne").prop("src","medium.jpg").width(400).height(267);

      }else if (n < 135){
      $("#pictureOne").prop("src","small.jpg").width(200).height(134);
      }
      });
  </script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:801px) and (max-width:5000px)" href="large.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:601px) and (max-width:800px)" href="medium.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:10px) and (max-width:600px)" href="small.css" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

 <div class="content">
    <img id="pictureOne" src="large.jpg" width="700" height="467">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are the external css sheets:

```
        Small
.content {position: relative; margin: 0px auto; width: 200px; height: 134px; border: 1px solid black;}

Medium
.content {position: relative; margin: 0px auto; width: 400px; height: 267px; border: 1px solid black;}

Large
.content {position: relative; margin: 0px auto; width: 700px; height: 467px; border: 1px solid black;}
```

Comment: try prop method and include in load function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This solution.

**CSS**

```
/* Large Media Query */
.content {position: relative; margin: 0px auto; width: 700px; height: 467px; border: 1px solid black;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    /* Small Media Query */
    .content {height: 267px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    /* Small Media Query */
    .content {height: 134px;}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <img id="pictureOne" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/check_alt-48.png" >
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function setLayout(){

      var n = $(".content").height(),
            url = 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/';
    switch(n){
        case 134:
            $("#pictureOne").attr("src", url+"check_alt-24.png");
            break;
        case 267:
            $("#pictureOne").attr("src", url+"check_alt-32.png");
            break;
        default:
            $("#pictureOne").attr("src", url+"check_alt-48.png");
    }

};

$(document).on('resize ready', function(){ setLayout() });
$(window).on('resize', function(){ setLayout() });
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ze2GR/4/)**

Comment: Thank you very much Rakesh for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `width()` and `height()` are functions, and can be used like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var n = $(".content").height();
      if (n < 268){
          $("#pictureOne").prop("src","medium.jpg").width(400).height(267);

      }else if (n < 135) {
          $("#pictureOne").prop("src","medium.jpg").width(200).height(134)
      } 
});
```

Note that you're also missing brackets in the condition and you should be using `prop()` to change properties, like `src`.

Comment: Thank you for your help and code. I have updated my code but am still unable to get my images to change properly.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery .height() is a method, you need to invoke it to get the height.

So

```
var n = $(".content").height();
```